# Non-isogrammatic nine-letter words from a 23-letter alphabet

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many words would have at least one repeated letter?

So far I have $23^9$, but I don't know what else to write.

Comment: $23^9$ is presumably the number of $9$-letter words.  How many do not have a repeated letter?

Comment: I am aware of this, it is the part that says atleast that confuses me

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with situations such as "at least", it is sometimes easier to find the number of ways the condition **isn't** satisfied and subtracting this from all possible combinations.

You want to find the number of combinations of words that have at least one repeated letter so let's instead find the numbers of combinations of words that **don't** fulfill this property i.e. the number of combinations of words that have no repeated letters.

How many combinations of words are there with no repeated letters? Well you have 23 choices in the first position, 22 in the second, 21 in the third etc. until all nine positions are filled. Thus the number of combinations of words with no repeated letters is:

$$
23 \times 22 \times 21 \times \dots \times 15 = \frac{23!}{14!}
$$

And the number of total possible combinations as you have mentioned is $23^9$. So the number of combinations that have at least one repeated word is

$$
n = 23^9 - \frac{23!}{14!} = 1,504,610,754,250
$$